# I tried to redirect my php page to another after filling a form but it only works in localhost but not on webhost

Tags: php, html, sql

From the loginPage.php, I am trying to redirect the page to index.php after logging in. But what happen is the form is just refresh after I tried logging in.

**header.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
    <?php
    session_start();
    $servername = "localhost";
    $usernameDB = "root";
    $passwordDB = "";
    $dbname = "myfirstdb";

    // Create connection
    $con = new mysqli($servername, $usernameDB, $passwordDB, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($con->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    ?>
```

loginPage.php:

```
<?php include_once("header.php") ?>

<?php
// initial
$username_input = $password_input = "";
$invalid_err = $username_err = $password_err = "";
$submit_form = FALSE;

// check if session log in
if (isset($_SESSION["login"]) && $_SESSION["login"] === true) {
    header("location: index.php");
    exit;
}

// form action
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $submit_form = TRUE;
        $username_input = $_POST['username'];
        $password_input = $_POST['password'];

        // table user
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$username_input';";
        $result = $con->query($sql);

        if (!$result || mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
            $invalid_err = "Invalid username or password";
        } else {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $userID = $row["userID"];
                $username = $row["username"];
                $password = $row['password'];
                $email = $row['email'];
            }
            if ($password_input == $password) {
                // Store data in session variables
                $_SESSION["login"] = true;
                $_SESSION["userID"] = $userID;
                $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
                header('Location: index.php');
                exit();
            } else {
                $invalid_err = "Invalid username or password";
            }
        }
    }
}
?>

</body>

</html>
```

The login form detected that I was able to login to the page means that I entered the correct username and password. But for some reason the header does not redirect the page to the **index.php**. Its just refresh the form. When I try on localhost it works very well but not on webhost. Why does this happen?

Comment: Do you get a "headers already sent" error? You've already sent output to the browser as part of your `header.php`, so that should prevent another header being sent. The fact that it worked on your dev machine suggests that is configured with output buffering, and your live server is not. I don't really any point for having that html in the position it's in, so you could remove it and see if that helps.

Comment: You also seem to be storing passwords in plain text - this is A Bad Thing. Look at `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` to see how to do it. Also look at Prepared Statements instead of sticking variables directly into your query like that.

Comment: You seem to be creating a lot of variables in that code for no apparent reason. Your `while` loop is a bit pointless too, presuming you've set the `username` column to be unique.

Comment: What happens when the user provides a bad username or password? Here, you seem to set a variable `$invalid_err` and then just close the page. Shouldn't you be displaying that error, or re-drawing the form?

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt from [php.net][1]

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.

So, shift the include line for header.php to just before the **\form action** and after the if block for the **header** command.

```
  [1]: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php
```